# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert a piece of text into my linked list. However, when ever I try to do this I get an error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'". I am writing this in python 3.3.

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, item= None , link= None ):
    self.item = item
    self.next = link

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.item)


class List:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.count = 0

def is_empty(self):
    return self.count == 0

def is_full(self):
    return False

def reset(self):
    self.__init__()

def __len__(self):
    return self.count

def _getNode(self, index):
    node = self.head
    for _ in range(index):
        node = node.next
    return node

def insert(self, index, item):
    if index < 0:
        index = 0

    elif index > len(self):
        index = len(self)

    if index == 0:
        self.head = Node(item, self.head)
    else:
        node = self._getNode(index - 1)
        node.next = Node(item, node.next)

    self.count += 1

def delete(self, index):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise IndexError("List is empty")
    if index < 0 or index >= len(self):
        raise IndexError("Index is out of range")

    if index == 0:
        self.head = self.head.next
    else:
        node = self._getNode(index - 1)
        node.next = node.next.next

    self.count -= 1

import LinkedList
text= LinkedList.List()

def insert_num(line,text):
    text.insert(line - 1,text)

def delete_num(line):
    if line is None:
        text.reset
    else:
        text.delete(line)

def print_num(line):
    if line is None:
        i= 0
        while i< line.count:
            item= text._getNode(i)
            print (item)
    else:
        print(text._getNode(line))

while True:
    print("1. Insert")
    print("2. Delete")
    print("3. Print")
    print("4. Quit")
    command = int(input())
    if command == 1:
        line = int(input("At what line do you wish to insert your text?: "))
        text = input("Text: ")
        insert_num(line,text)
    elif command == 2:
        line = int(input("What line do you wish to delete?: "))
        delete_num(line)
    elif command == 3:
        line = int(input("What line do you wish to print?: "))
    elif command == 4:
        break
    else:
        print("invalid input, please select one of the following numbers:")
```

Comment: Don't write "Ps sorry for the wall of code", boil your code down to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) _before asking_!

Comment: Please do not edit questions to mention they're answered. Accept an answer, instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your main loop, you call `insert_num(line, text)`. But `text` here is the text string you inputted above, not the global variable `text` which is an instance of your LinkedList class. As the error says, strings don't have an insert method (because they are immutable).

Answer (score 1):

You call these two lines

```
text = input("Text: ")
insert_num(line,text)
```

The resulting `text` variable will be type `str`, not a linked list. Strings do not have an `insert`, as the error is telling you.

And when you call these two lines:

```
import LinkedList
text= LinkedList.List()
```

That is a different `text` variable than the one that exists within the scope of your `insert_num` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is variable scoping. When you call your `insert_num()` procedure you want to insert your new line (the `text` parameter, which is of type str) into your `LinkedList` of lines, which is also called `text` but because the method has a parameter with the same name, this (the linked list) is outside of the scope, and so can't be seen by the procedure.

```
text= LinkedList.List()

def insert_num(line,text):
    text.insert(line - 1,text)
```

I'd rename the subroutine's parameter:

```
text= LinkedList.List()

def insert_num(line_number, new_line):
    text.insert(line_number - 1,new_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

.insert() Method can be used with list only, but you are trying to use it with a string. That is why you are getting error